# SurgeQueueLength equivalent for Application Load Balancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm looking to set up Auto-Scaling for a service running on AWS ECS. From the [ECS Auto-Scaling docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html) it suggests to use `SurgeQueueLength` to determine whether to trigger an autoscale event. We use an Application Load Balancer [which does not have this metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html), looking through the table of metrics nothing seems equivalent. Am I missing something or is this just a missing feature in ALBs at present?

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: I don't have experience with Application Load Balancers. I'm just deriving these facts from AWS docs. For a more hands on read you might read [the ALB section of this medium post](https://medium.com/@steve.mushero/load-balancers-sre-golden-signals-de8a98c74020#71c0)*

You are correct, in the [CloudWatch metrics for Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html) there is no `SurgeQueueLength`. This is also confirmed in [this thread by an AWS employee](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246865&tstart=0), however, these metrics *could* be used as a CloudWatch metric to trigger auto scaling:

- `TargetConnectionErrorCount`: IMO this is corresponding best to the `SurgeQueueLength` as it indicates that the Loadbalancer tried to open a connection to a backend node and failed
- `HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count`: depending on the backend nodes this might be an indicator that they refuse new connections because e.g. their max connection count is reached
- `RejectedConnectionCount`: this is what the AWS employee suggested in the treadh linked above. Buuut.. the doc says "number of connections that were rejected because the load balancer had reached its maximum number of connections" this seems more like a limit on aws side which you cannot really influence (i.e. it is not described in the [limits on ALBs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html))
- `RequestCountPerTarget`: that's the average number of connections a backend node gets per minute. When you track that over a period of time you might be able to evaluate a "healthy threshold"
- `TargetResponseTime`: number of seconds a backend node needs to answer a request. Another candidate for evaluating as "healthy threshold" (i.e. "what's the maximum response time you want the end user to experience?")

Overall it seems that there is no "clear correct answer" to your question and the answer is a "it depends on your situation".

The question which suggests itself is: "why are there no queue metrics such as SurgeQueueLength". This is nowhere answered in the docs. I guess this is either because ALBs are designed differently than ELBs *or* it is a metric which is just not exposed yet.

Comment: Just to add a comment about that: ALB doesn't use surge queues because AWS concluded that it was actually a bad idea (based on the ELB feedbacks). So they prefer to refuse connections and have fresh requests; instead of basically queuing requests and treat them when the client is gone :p

Answer (score 0):

ALBs are designed differently and don't have `SurgeQueueLength` or `SpillOver` metrics. Source: AWS Staff.