# How do I limit the requests to upstream server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am looking into using Amazon Load Balancer. I am not finding any documentation on following or if and how they can be achieved:

Say my target server supports 2k requests per second and ALB receives 4k requests in one second. In such case, I want ALB to forward 2k requests to target server in first second, keep remaining 2k in a queue in ALB and forward them to target server next second.

Is that even possible? Any hints/links/references would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SurgeQueueLength equivalent for Application Load Balancers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856103/surgequeuelength-equivalent-for-application-load-balancers)

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible as you describe it. AWS Load Balancers don't store requests in a queue. If a server isn't available to handle a request then storing the requests in a queue until a server was available could cause requests to hang for minutes, which can result in client-timeouts and generally bad experience for end users.

Ideally you would be seeing that amount of traffic ramp-up over a period of time, and you would have your auto-scaling group configured so that by the time your traffic increased from 2k to 4k requests you would already have another server in your pool to handle the traffic.